# Pythonic way to check how many items in a list or combination of items match a condition

Tags: python, python-3.x

Say I have a list like this:

```
l = [20,17,8,7,4,9]
```

I would like to check how many items or combinations of items match a value condition.

To check the single items this would do:

```
minimum_value = 12
count = 0
for item in l:
    if item >= minimum_value:
        count += 1
```

But I also would like to check combinations of that list. Then the count would be 4: 20, 17, 9+4, 8+7

How could I do this?

Comment: what is the criteria for getting `20, 17, 9+4, 8+7` as your output?

Comment: What about 8+4, 7+9? And what about combinations of 3 or more items?

Comment: I am looking for possible combinations that match the condition. If an item is used it cannot be used again. My thought was to build a second loop after a single item does not match the condition and add the smallest item (or next smallest after that).

Comment: But that would. It work if I need more than two items to match the condition. ( like in [20,12,4,5,2,2]

Comment: - would not work -

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by checking the total value at the each iteration. If the total is larger than the minimum value, increase the count and reset the total. Otherwise, add the number from the next iteration to the total and check again.

```
l = [20,17,8,7,4,9]

minimum_value = 12
count = 0
sum = 0
for item in l:
    sum += item
    if sum >= minimum_value:
        count += 1
        sum = 0

print(count)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you want to check all values plus all combinations of values against a minimum value and return the count of such.  The following code will do this.

Note: there is probably a more concise way to do this, but I feel this is the easiest to read.

```
l = [20, 17, 8, 7, 4, 9]
minimum_value = 12
count = 0

newl = [] # Create a new list to store all the different combinations
for i in range(len(l)): # Get each index in l
    newl.append(l[i]) # Append the value at the current index to newl
    for n in l[i+1:]: # Loop through the remaining numbers starting at index + 1
        newl.append(l[i] + n) # Combine

count = len([x for x in newl if x >= minimum_value])  # Get the length of a list generated by taking all numbers in newl that are >= minimum_value
print(count)
```

In the above case, `newl` contains:
`[20, 37, 28, 27, 24, 29, 17, 25, 24, 21, 26, 8, 15, 12, 17, 7, 11, 16, 4, 13, 9]`

And thus has `16` values that exceed the `minimum_value` of `12`

Comment: This works great but I can only use items once. So I am looking for the best possible use of the items. My thought was to try sorting items by value and then combine from the first largest value that does not match the condition.

Comment: Maybe it would be an option to make a list of lists with every possible combination an then choose len of largest list. It seems a bit bulky though.